# perform function when page loads in webOS

Tags: javascript, webos

I am currently trying to create a database in webOS for which I can later perform crud operations. So far, the users need to click on a button to create the database and another to create the table. Is there a way that these can be created when the application loads so that the user does not have to do it himself?

EDIT:

This is an Enyo application and I am using HTML5 for the database, so basically I want to be able to openDatabase and create a table when the application loads.

Comment: Can you be more specific about whether this is a Mojo application, an Enyo application or something else altogether?

Comment: @Pre101 I edited the post above

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to override the `create` function of your app kind to check if database is initialized and then create it as necessary.  Alternately, you could start with a splash screen and perform the necessary functions and when completed, load your main kind.

Here's an article on splash screens:

https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/app_splash_screens.html

Or there's an splash screen kind someone created:

https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16262